# I have no control when I run a page with edge IE in selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to send actions to the page that I open with IE mode in Edge.
I don't know if I would need any other type of connection or configuration for it

selenium v4.2.0 (python)
edge(Versión 102.0.1245.39)
IEDRIVER v4.2.0.0

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time


ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()


ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)

ieOptions.add_additional_option(
"ie.edgepath", 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')

driver = webdriver.Ie(
r"C:\\seleniumEdge\\IEDriverServer.exe", options=ieOptions)
driver.get("http://www.bing.com")
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'sb_form_q')
elem.send_keys('WebDriver' + Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _...I have no control..._

Comment: when running in Edge I need to be able to send information to x id field but when doing so the information does not reach that field

Comment: How about Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: the page I need to run is very old and only runs with Internet Explore

Comment: Why would `http://www.bing.com` be very old?

Comment: It is a corporate page but to make the example we use bing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Keys.RETURN` you have first to import `Keys`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```